# Text replacement in all the files in a directory

Tags: regex, windows, perl

In windows 2008, we have multiple files in a directory. The files are having paths as contents and those texts should be replaced with other string.Find example below:

The files are having the paths like:

File1:

C:\Apps\ **etc\A1**\X.exe should be replaced with C:\Apps\ **exe**\X.exe

File2:

C:\Apps\ **etc\B1**\Y.exe should be replaced with C:\Apps\ **exe**\Y.exe

I am trying to find a single command which will replace the bold lettered strings as mentioned above.

In case of normal strings I use the below command and it works:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN{@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV} s/string1/string2/g" ./*.txt
```

But the current requirement seems to use regular expression for which I am not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace etc\ followed by anything up to a \ again with just exe:

```
's/etc\\[^\\]*\\/exe\\/g'
```

Comment: thanks..It works for me..what should be the expression if i need to replace '\\abc' with 'a:\bc'..can u pls suggest..

Comment: @user1706047: `:` isn't special in regular expressions, but you need to double backslashes.

Comment: I need to have a page break in the html pages those are combined into a single page: so i am trying to replace the "</BODY>"  to   "<div style='page-break-after:always;'>&nbsp;</Div></BODY>". I am using the below command with '&' as a matching string as used in sed command. But it doesnt work here . perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN{@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV} s/<\/BODY/<div style=\'page-break-after:always;\'>\&nbsp;<\/Div>&/g" test.html , can you please suggest a solution here.

Comment: Perl uses the `$&` variable instead of `&`.